# How can I deploy elasticsearch cluster in input region in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cdk, aws-elasticsearch

I wanted to deploy an es cluster in the region provided in input. I am able to deploy es using cdk. Below is the code I used,

```
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');
import {CfnDomain} from '@aws-cdk/aws-elasticsearch';

export class RegionalInfraCreation extends cdk.Construct {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);
    let globalTableName = 'regional_infra'
    let region = 'eu-west-1'
    let profileName = 'default'

    // es cluster 
    // @ts-ignore
    const elasticsearchDomain = new CfnDomain(this,
      'ElasticsearchDomain',
      {
        accessPolicies: {
          Version: '2012-10-17',
          Statement: [
            {
              Effect: 'Allow',
              Principal: {
                AWS: '*',
              },
              Action: 'es:*',
              Resource: "arn:aws:es:*:*:domain/*/*",
            },
          ],
        },
        ebsOptions: {
          ebsEnabled: true,
          volumeSize: 10,
          volumeType: 'standard',
        },
        elasticsearchClusterConfig: {
          instanceCount: 1,
          instanceType: 't2.medium.elasticsearch',
        },
        domainName: 'test-cluster',
        elasticsearchVersion: '7.4',
      }
    );
    console.log('logical id es')
    console.log(elasticsearchDomain.logicalId)
  }
}
```

Now using this, I am able to deploy es cluster in single region(lets say us-east-1). Now I want to give input to this to deploy the cluster in different region(eu-west-1). How could I update region of elasticsearch like something possible in other services And also how could I get logical id for created resouce. I dont want stack to create in different region, I want something like below present in dynamo i.e. update the region,

```
const dynamodb = new Dynamodb({
      region: region
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

CDK generates a CFn template and it needs to be deployed to a specific region. If the intention is to switch/change the target region where the CFn script is deployed to create an ES within a CDK script, there is no such way.

CDK deploy gets tied to a specific region CDK_DEFAULT_REGION in which AWS resources get created.

CDK [Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html)

> Each Stack instance in your AWS CDK app is explicitly or implicitly associated with an environment (env). An environment is the target AWS account and AWS Region into which the stack is intended to be deployed.

If the intention is to make the CDK script and the generated CFn template region agnostic, then not specifying the CDK environment.

> The AWS CDK distinguishes between not specifying the env property at all and specifying it using CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT and CDK_DEFAULT_REGION. The former implies that the stack should synthesize an environment-agnostic template.